# problem in javascript remoting

Tags: javascript-remoting

VF:

```
<apex:page controller="jsclass">
<apex:form >
<script>
  function getValue(){
    var fieldValue = document.getElementById('test').value;
    Visualforce.remoting.Manager.invokeAction('{!$RemoteAction.jsclass.addAccounts}',acc,function(result, event)
    {
        if (event.status)
        {
           document.getElementById("{!$Component.theBlock.pbs.pbs1.accId}")
                                  .innerHTML = result.Id;
        }
    },{escape:true});
  }
</script>
<apex:inputtext id="test"/>
<apex:pageBlock id="theBlock" >
<apex:pageBlockSection id="pbs" >
<apex:pageblocksectionitem id="pbs1">
<apex:outputtext id="accId">
</apex:outputtext>
</apex:pageblocksectionitem>
</apex:pageBlockSection>
</apex:pageBlock> 
</apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

---

class:

---

```
public class jsclass {
public string acc {get; set;}
public account a {get; set;}
@RemoteAction
    public static void addAccounts(string acc){
      String ac = acc.Substring(0,acc.length()-1);
       Account a =[Select Id from account where name like'%ac'];
       system.debug(a);
}
}
```

Comment: Can you please provide more details on what error you are receiving and what line it is occurring on?

Comment: no errors i cant see the recordid corresponds to the name i enter

Comment: In your select statement you have where name like '%ac' when you should most likely have where name like :acc so that you are keying off the parameter and not the static string. Also in your javascript I don't see where you set the acc parameter you are passing in.

Comment: To add to @techbusinessman's comment, `String acLike = '%' + ac;` and `name like :acLike`. But you are returning nothing either so its hard to see what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

I could not find where you are calling the `getValue()` function also you are not returning anything from your `addAccounts()` method. Below is the working version of your code. I tried to update the code to meet your requirement. I am calling `getValue()` method form `onkeyup()` event on the input text. The `addAccounts()` is now returning Account object matching the name. You can update further based on your need. Hope this helps.

**VF Page**

```
<apex:page controller="jsclass">
  <apex:form >
    <script>
          function getValue(){
            var fieldValue = document.getElementById("{!$Component.test}").value;
            Visualforce.remoting.Manager.invokeAction('{!$RemoteAction.jsclass.addAccounts}',fieldValue,function(result, event){
                if (event.status){
                   document.getElementById("{!$Component.theBlock.pbs.pbs1.accId}").innerHTML = result.Id;
                }
            },{escape:true});
          }
    </script>   
    <apex:inputtext id="test" onkeyup="getValue();" />
    <apex:pageBlock id="theBlock" >
      <apex:pageBlockSection id="pbs">
        <apex:pageblocksectionitem id="pbs1">
          <apex:outputText id="accId" value="accId"/>
        </apex:pageblocksectionitem>
      </apex:pageBlockSection>
    </apex:pageBlock>       
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

**Controller**

```
public class jsclass {
public string acc {get; set;}
public account a {get; set;}
@RemoteAction
    public static Account addAccounts(string acc){
       String ac = '%' + acc.Substring(0,acc.length()-1) +'%';
       Account a =[Select Id from account where name like :ac limit 1];
       system.debug(a);
       return a;
    }
}
```

Comment: @Vidhyasagaran Muralidhara If it was the answer can you please mark it as answer. Thanks.